# Magento2 : How to override /vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php

Tags: magento2, overrides, exception

Does anyone know how to override this file?

Answer (score 0):

If the default magento preferences dont work,
I think you can use composer's autoload functionality for that, add something like this to your composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
},
"psr-0": {
    "\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler": "vendor-custom/handler/streamhandler",
}
```

},

I didnt test this so it could be wrong.
More info about this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600844/composer-override-a-package-file